# java me: start playing mp3 file from the 2nd minute and stop on the fourth minute. mp3 file is of 6 minutes

Tags: java-me, mp3, media-player, mobile-phones

i need to  start playing a local resource mp3 file from the 2nd minute and stop on the fourth minute. mp3 file is of 6 minutes.

im new to this and couldn't find an example for the below code, could some1 pls point me to something like below?

long setMediaTime(long now)

i have other files also which i want to do the same with different numbers, it would be best if i could do this in milliseconds.. i am using this code to play the file..

```
 {
try
{
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nn.mp3");
Player  p =  Manager.createPlayer(is,"audio/mpeg");

p.realize();


{

}
p.prefetch();
p.start();
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
}
```

thanking u in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `p.setLoopCount( );` method.
Just have a look [here](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/)

Comment: that is not what i asked.. i want to start playing the file somewhere in the middle.. like if a mp3 file is of 6 mins duration then i want to start playing from somewhere like the 3rd min and stop at like 5th min..